# Task.WhenAny acting like Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, async-await, priority-queue, tpl-dataflow, bufferblock

I wrote a little program to test using BufferBlock (System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow) to implement a dual-priority consumer-producer queue.

The consumer should always use any items from the high-priority queue first.

In this initial test, I have the producer running at a much slower rate than the consumer, so the data should just come out in the same order it went in, regardless of priority.

However, I find that the result of `Task.WhenAny()` is not completing until there is something in both queues (or there's a completion), thus acting like `Task.WhenAll()`.

I thought I understood `async`/`await`, and I've perused Cleary's "Concurrency in C# Cookbook."  However, there is something going on that I'm not understanding.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;  // add nuget package, 4.8.0
using static System.Console;

namespace DualBufferBlockExample { // .Net Framework 4.6.1

    class Program {
        private static async Task Produce(BufferBlock<int> queueLo, BufferBlock<int> queueHi, IEnumerable<int> values) {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            foreach(var value in values) {
                if(value == 3 || value == 7)
                    await queueHi.SendAsync(value);
                else
                    await queueLo.SendAsync(value);
                WriteLine($"Produced {value}  qL.Cnt={queueLo.Count} qH.Cnt={queueHi.Count}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);  // production lag
            }

            queueLo.Complete();
            queueHi.Complete();
        }
        private static async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Consume(BufferBlock<int> queueLo, BufferBlock<int> queueHi) {
            var results = new List<int>();

            while(true) {
                int value = -1;

                while(queueLo.Count > 0 || queueHi.Count > 0) {  // take from hi-priority first
                    if(queueHi.TryReceive(out value) ||
                        queueLo.TryReceive(out value)) {  // process value
                        results.Add(value);
                        WriteLine($"    Consumed {value}");
                        await Task.Delay(100); // consumer processing time shorter than production
                    }
                }

                var hasNorm = queueHi.OutputAvailableAsync();
                var hasLow = queueLo.OutputAvailableAsync();
                var anyT = await Task.WhenAny(hasNorm, hasLow);  // <<<<<<<<<< behaves like WhenAll
                WriteLine($"  WhenAny {anyT.Result} qL.Result={hasLow.Result} qH.Result={hasNorm.Result} qL.Count={queueLo.Count} qH.Count={queueHi.Count}");

                if(!anyT.Result)
                    break;  // both queues are empty & complete
            }

            return results;
        }
        static async Task TestDataFlow() {
            var queueLo = new BufferBlock<int>();
            var queueHi = new BufferBlock<int>();

            // Start the producer and consumer.
            var consumer = Consume(queueLo, queueHi);
            WriteLine("Consumer Started");

            var producer = Produce(queueLo, queueHi, Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
            WriteLine("Producer Started");

            // Wait for everything to complete.
            await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer, queueLo.Completion, queueHi.Completion);

            // show consumer's output
            var results = await consumer;

            Write("Results:");
            foreach(var x in results)
                Write($" {x}");
            WriteLine();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                TestDataFlow().Wait();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                WriteLine($"TestDataFlow exception: {ex.ToString()}");
            }
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Consumer Started
Producer Started
Produced 0  qL.Cnt=1 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 1  qL.Cnt=2 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 2  qL.Cnt=3 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 3  qL.Cnt=3 qH.Cnt=1
  WhenAny True qL.Result=True qH.Result=True qL.Count=3 qH.Count=1
    Consumed 3
    Consumed 0
    Consumed 1
    Consumed 2
Produced 4  qL.Cnt=1 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 5  qL.Cnt=2 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 6  qL.Cnt=3 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 7  qL.Cnt=3 qH.Cnt=1
  WhenAny True qL.Result=True qH.Result=True qL.Count=3 qH.Count=1
    Consumed 7
    Consumed 4
    Consumed 5
    Consumed 6
Produced 8  qL.Cnt=1 qH.Cnt=0
Produced 9  qL.Cnt=2 qH.Cnt=0
  WhenAny True qL.Result=True qH.Result=False qL.Count=2 qH.Count=0
    Consumed 8
    Consumed 9
  WhenAny False qL.Result=False qH.Result=False qL.Count=0 qH.Count=0
Results: 3 0 1 2 7 4 5 6 8 9
```

Comment: Please could you format your code in a more conventional way? This style of indentation is very rare within the C# world - aim for writing a question in a way that potential answerers will find as easy to read as possible.

Comment: @roki when you call `WriteLine` immediately following `Task.WhenAny` you block on both tasks and force execution to wait there until both have completed. In other words `qL.Result={hasLow.Result} qH.Result={hasNorm.Result}` blocks on both tasks using `.Result`

Comment: @JSteward I suspect you're 100% right - should probably add as an answer; to roki: you should **never** access `.Result` on a task that isn't known to be complete - you'll get away with it in a console, but in many scenarios: that can deadlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `WhenAny` your immediately blocking on both tasks using `.Result` without knowing that they're both complete.

```
var anyT = await Task.WhenAny(hasNorm, hasLow);

//This line blocks on both the hasNorm and hasLow tasks preventing execution from continuing. 
WriteLine($"  WhenAny {anyT.Result} qL.Result={hasLow.Result} qH.Result={hasNorm.Result} qL.Count={queueLo.Count} qH.Count={queueHi.Count}");
```

`awaiting` both tasks will also give you the same behavior. The best you can do is `await` the task returned from `WhenAny` and only print the results from the completed task.

Additionally, a priority queue is not something that `TPL-Dataflow` does well out of the box. It treats all messages equally so you end plugging in your own priority implementation. That said you can [make it work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48265027/7339946).

Comment: I knew it was something like that.  Thanks so much!